# Add a condition to an if statement based on only one of the different parameters of an object

Tags: java, if-statement

I created a digraph using the jgrapht library, and it takes as vertices `Point`objects I created. These objects take as parameters two coordinates and a type. I made a simple and short example:

```
public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
public static Point firstPoint = new Point(2, 7, "A");
public static Point secondPoint = new Point(2, 8, "B");
public static Point thirdPoint = new Point(2, 9, "B");
public static Point fourthPoint = new Point(2, 4, "C");


void setup () {
  directedGraph.addVertex(firstPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(secondPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(thirdPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(fourthPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(firstPoint, secondPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(secondPoint, thirdPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(secondPoint, fourthPoint);



  int degree = directedGraph.outDegreeOf(secondPoint);
  if (degree >= 2) { 
    for (Point successor : Graphs.successorListOf (directedGraph, secondPoint)) {
      if (/*the iD is equal to B*/){
      for (Point predecessor : Graphs.predecessorListOf (directedGraph, secondPoint )) {
        directedGraph.addEdge(predecessor, successor);
      }
    }
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
public static ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
public static class Point {

  public int x;
  public int y;
  public String iD;
  public  Point(int x, int y, String iD) 
  {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.iD= iD;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[x="+x+" y="+y+" iD="+iD+ "]");
  }

  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.y;

    return hash;
  }



  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) 
  {
    if (this == other)
      return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Point))
      return false;

    Point otherPoint = (Point) other;
    return otherPoint.x == x && otherPoint.y == y;
  }
}
```

I'd like to add a condition in the if statement on the iD of the vertices, but not on the two other parameters of my Point objects. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then yes it's possible. Use the `public` `iD` field. Something like,

```
for (Point successor : Graphs.successorListOf (directedGraph, secondPoint)) {
    // if (/*the iD is equal to B*/){
    if (successor.iD.equals("B")){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined it as a `public` field. You can access it by using `.` Just do:

```
if (successor.iD.equals("B")) {
```

See: [Oracle Tutorial on Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)